# Selenium unusual output in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am getting comments from website I tried it already and it worked well but now it gives me unusual output.

Part of my code:

```
comments = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("comment-text")
time.sleep(1)
print(comments[1])
```

The output:

`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bb6ae0409dd8ec8c191f9bd84f79bea7", element="5f5d4a2f-7a93-41fe-9ca5-aa4e7c525792")>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
print(comments[1].text)
```

You were printing the element itself which is just some GUID (I think). I'm assuming you want the text contained in the element which means you need `.text`.